# VSCode terminal uses different configuration for bash when launched from WSL

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run windows terminal and start a bash session to WSL (Ubuntu) I am not going to the same place or calling the same bashrc file to load session info. packages that I install through Windows terminal WSL are not available in a bash session from VScode running in WSL.

From VScode I am running a WSL session in Ubuntu (20.04), I choose the same WSL session when using Windows terminal Both VScode (C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04)

Comment: You may have multiple WSL instances installed.  Compare the results of `echo $WSL_DISTRO_NAME` from both inside VSCode vs. launching WSL directly.  Are they the same?

Comment: I confirmed that both VScode and Windows terminal appear to be using the same WSL instance, but it maybe something related to who they are logging in as? An example is I nstalled brew in from windows terminal. If I close all terminal sessions and re-open VScode I cannot run brew, but from windows terminal I can

Comment: For reviewers - It's not clear why this was closed as requesting recommendation for off-site resources.  IMHO, this is a completely valid question and deserves reopening (and hopefully, an answer).

Comment: Can you compare a few more things?  First, see if both are running as a login shell with `shopt login_shell`.  Also, since you mention "who they are logging in as", confirm that with `echo $USER` in both.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thanks for following up on this, I modified the original question and that seems to have fixed the closed issue. I checked what you suggested,

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thanks for following up on this, I modified the original question and that seems to have fixed the closed issue. I checked what you suggested,
both terminal and Vscode have the same user. the login_shell though is different 
Terminal - on 
VScode - off
Checking the $path variable, the value is different for Windows Terminal vs VScode. 
Another variable that is different is the argument 0 (echo $0) 
Terminal - -bash
VScode - /bin/bash

It appears the way the shell is accessed in Terminal vs VScode is different, which would likely is the cause of the differences.